# Why Wolfram Cloud doesn't simplify below BBP type sum, which I came up with?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

Why Wolfram Cloud don't simplify below BBP type sum, which I came up with:

```
simplify Sum((1/81)^(k+1)*(9/(2*k+1)+1/(2*k+2)),k = 0 .. infinity)
```

to

```
2*log(3) - 3*log(2)
```

?

I would expect to see in the output

```
2*log(3) - 3*log(2)
```

or at least

```
log(9)/log(8)
```

but instead the output is:

```
ArcTanh[1/9]+1/2 Log[81/80]
```

?

PS Here are the messages I have received on WOLFRAM COMMUNITY where I also posted my question:

1. With Mathematica I get simplification with FullSimplify, but not with Simplify alone.
2. Both Wolfram Alpha and Wolfram Cloud are powerful computational platforms, but there could be several reasons why a specific mathematical expression might not simplify as expected:

Algorithmic Limitations: While these platforms have advanced algorithms, there are cases where certain simplifications aren't recognized, especially for non-standard or less common forms.

Input Interpretation: The way you've input the expression might lead the software to interpret or process it differently than intended.

Complexity: Some expressions, even if they have simpler forms, might be perceived as computationally expensive to evaluate or simplify, leading to timeouts or incomplete.

Comment: Typing `Sum[(1/81)^(k + 1)*(9/(2*k + 1) + 1/(2*k + 2)), {k, 0, Infinity}]` into WolframAlpha produces `Log[9/8]` as one of the alternate forms, so maybe putting the input into mma form helps

Answer (score 1):

When I try

```
simplify Sum((1/81)^(k+1)(9/(2k+1)+1/(2*k+2)),k = 0 .. infinity)
```

in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%20Sum%28%281%2F81%29%5E%28k%2B1%29%289%2F%282k%2B1%29%2B1%2F%282*k%2B2%29%29%2Ck%20%3D%200%20..%20infinity%29)

it shows me three different forms of the result, the first one is log(9/8)

When I try Wolfram Mathematica in the cloud

```
FullSimplify[Sum[(1/81)^(k+1)(9/(2k+1)+1/(2*k+2)),{k,0,Infinity}]]
```

it returns

```
Log[9/8]
```

Are you and I doing exactly the same thing and getting different results? Or is this just the form of the output made you think we were getting different results?